# Error: cURL error 28: Resolving timed out after 10000 milliseconds (http_request_failed) with nginx reverse proxy in docker

Tags: wordpress, docker, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am trying to set up a local Wordpress environment using Docker Compose with Nginx reverse proxy. WordPress. works but in Site Health I get:

```
Error: cURL error 28: Resolving timed out after 10000 milliseconds (http_request_failed)
```

This my docker-compose file

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  web:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf
    depends_on:
      - wordpress
      - db

  wordpress:
    image: wordpress
    expose:
      - 80
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: local_user
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: secret
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: local
    volumes:
      - ./wordpress:/var/www/html

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: local
      MYSQL_USER: local_user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root_secret
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
```

this is my Nginx config file:

```
upstream backend{
    server wordpress:80;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    index index.php index.html;
    server_name bedrock.local; 
    # error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    # access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    # root /code/web;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend/;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }

}
```

bedrock.local domain resolves locally with 127.0.0.1 in /etc/hosts
I'm not using HTTPS (just HTTP) to simplify the test.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, Wordpress container cannot reach the website on the public IP address due to the Docker networking.

The best solution to this is to add the fqdn aliases to the Nginx container in the docker-compose.yml file to allow Wordpress to reach Nginx internally.

This config will solve the issue:

```
web:
  image: nginx
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  volumes:
    - ./site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf
  depends_on:
    - wordpress
    - db
  networks:
    default:
      aliases:
        - yourwebsite.com
        - www.yourwebsite.com
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and discovered it was because the name resolution was funky for the root domain due to a split DNS i run.

Adding extra_hosts fixed it for me

```
...
   wordpress:
     image: wordpress:latest
     ports:
       - 8080:80
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: xxxxxxx
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD:xxxxxx
       WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpressdb
     extra_hosts:
       - mydomain.com:internal or external loopback IP has needed
       - www.mydomain.com:internal or external loopback IP has needed
       - blog.mydomain.com:internal or external loopback IP has needed
...
```